# Route planner two dimensional array

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm doing Java tasks from this website https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/route-planner/41102
and got stuck on `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. When you debug code I'll get to finish, but right after that you will get array index is out of bounds. If you open website you will see full task with picture for better understanding. What am I doing wrong?

```java
public static boolean routeExists(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow,
                                  int toColumn, boolean[][] mapMatrix) {
    if (fromRow == mapMatrix.length - 1 && fromColumn == mapMatrix.length - 1) {
        return true;
    }

    goRight(fromRow, fromColumn, mapMatrix);
    goDown(fromRow, fromColumn, mapMatrix);

    return false;
}

private static void goRight(int one, int two, boolean[][] matrix) {
    try {
        if (matrix[one][two + 1]) {
            routeExists(one, two + 1, matrix.length - 1,
                    matrix.length - 1, matrix);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignore) {
        System.out.println("throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
}

private static void goDown(int one, int two, boolean[][] matrix) {
    try {
        if (matrix[one + 1][two]) {
            routeExists(one + 1, two, matrix.length - 1,
                    matrix.length - 1, matrix);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignore) {
        System.out.println("throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of ignoring the exception, make it print the stack trace, then share the full exception you are getting.

Comment: @StanvanderBend tried cant figure anyway

Comment: ? I am asking whether you can print the full stracktrace, replace
    `}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignore){
        System.out.println("throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }`
with
    `}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
and then edit your question to include the resulting error + stack trace, otherwise it's more difficult than need be for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer which passes all four tests:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RoutePlanner {

static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph;

public static boolean routeExists(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow, int toColumn, boolean[][] mapMatrix) {
    if(fromRow < 0 || fromColumn < 0 || toRow < 0 || toColumn < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if(fromRow >= mapMatrix.length || fromColumn >= mapMatrix[0].length || toRow >= mapMatrix.length || toColumn >= mapMatrix[0].length) {
        return false; 
    }
    if(!mapMatrix[fromRow][fromColumn] || !mapMatrix[toRow][toColumn]) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if(fromRow == toRow && fromColumn == toColumn) {
        return true;
    }
    
    constructGraph(mapMatrix);
    return bfs(fromRow + "-" + fromColumn, toRow + "-" + toColumn);
}


public static void constructGraph(boolean[][] mapMatrix) {
    graph = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mapMatrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mapMatrix[i].length; j++) {
            if(!mapMatrix[i][j]) {
                continue;
            }
            String currId = i + "-" + j;
            if(i-1 >= 0) {
                if(mapMatrix[i-1][j]) {
                    addEdge(currId, (i-1) + "-" + j);
                }
            }
            if(i+1 < mapMatrix.length) {
                if(mapMatrix[i+1][j]) {
                    addEdge(currId, (i+1) + "-" + j);
                }
            }
            if(j-1 >= 0) {
                if(mapMatrix[i][j-1]) {
                    addEdge(currId, i + "-" + (j-1));
                }
            }
            if(j+1 < mapMatrix[i].length) {
                if(mapMatrix[i][j+1]) {
                    addEdge(currId, i + "-" + (j+1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void addEdge(String from, String to) {
    if(graph.containsKey(from)) {
        graph.get(from).add(to);
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> neighbour = new ArrayList<String>();
        neighbour.add(to);
        graph.put(from, neighbour);
    }
}

public static boolean bfs(String start, String end) {
    LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();        // FIFO queue for BFS
    HashSet<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();
    
    queue.add(start);
    visited.add(start);
    
    String curr;
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        curr = queue.poll();
        
        if(curr.equals(end)) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if(!graph.containsKey(curr)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        for(String next : graph.get(curr)) {
            if(!visited.contains(next)) {
                visited.add(next);
                queue.add(next);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] mapMatrix = {
        {true,  false, false},
        {true,  true,  false},
        {false, true,  true}
    };
    System.out.println(routeExists(0, 0, 2, 2, mapMatrix));
    
}
}
```

I am first constructing a graph by connecting two matrix entries if they are adjacent and both are `true`.

Then, I am doing a simple Breadth-First Search through the graph, starting from the point `(fromRow, fromColumn)` and returning `true` once we reach the point `(toRow, toColumn)`, or returning `false` otherwise.

Note: I am using a String `i + "-" + j` to give each point in the matrix a unique id.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution to pass all 4 test cases:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RoutePlanner {
    
    public static boolean routeExists(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow, int toColumn,
                                      boolean[][] mapMatrix) {
        boolean[][] mapVisited = new boolean[mapMatrix.length][mapMatrix[0].length];
        
        return routeSearch(fromRow, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn,mapMatrix, mapVisited);
        
    }

    public static boolean routeSearch(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow, int toColumn,
                                      boolean[][] mapMatrix, boolean[][] mapVisited) {
        
      
        if(fromRow < 0 || fromColumn < 0 || fromRow >= mapMatrix.length || fromColumn >= mapMatrix[0].length)
            return false;
        
               
        if(mapVisited[fromRow][fromColumn] || !mapMatrix[fromRow][fromColumn]
           || !mapMatrix[toRow][toColumn])
            return false;
        
        if(fromRow == toRow && fromColumn == toColumn)
            return true;
        
        mapVisited[fromRow][fromColumn] = true;
        
        return routeSearch(fromRow-1, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix, mapVisited)
            || routeSearch(fromRow, fromColumn-1, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix, mapVisited)
            || routeSearch(fromRow+1, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix, mapVisited)            
            ||routeSearch(fromRow, fromColumn+1, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix, mapVisited);
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         boolean[][] mapMatrix = {
                {true, false, false},
                {true, true, false},
                {false, true, true}
        };
        System.out.println(routeExists(0, 0, 2, 2, mapMatrix));        
    }
}
```

Comment: I do love this one, simple & clear.

Answer (score 1):

My recursive solution to this question using `visited` helper matrix to prevent endless recursion of the same steps over and over:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RoutePlanner {


    public static boolean validMove(boolean[][] mapMatrix,boolean[][] visited, int row, int column) {
        if (row >= 0 && column >= 0 && row < mapMatrix.length && column < mapMatrix[row].length ) {
            if (mapMatrix[row][column] && !visited[row][column]) // check if move is valid & not visited yet
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean routeExists(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow, int toColumn,
                                      boolean[][] mapMatrix) {
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[mapMatrix.length][mapMatrix[0].length];
        return routeExistsHelper(fromRow,fromColumn,toRow,toColumn,mapMatrix,visited);
    }

    public static boolean routeExistsHelper(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow, int toColumn, boolean[][] mapMatrix, boolean[][] visited) {
        visited[fromRow][fromColumn] = true;
        if (fromRow == toRow && fromColumn == toColumn)
            return true;
        else {
            boolean left = false, right = false, up = false, down = false;
            if (validMove(mapMatrix,visited, fromRow + 1, fromColumn)) {
                right = routeExistsHelper(fromRow + 1, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix,visited);
            }
            if (validMove(mapMatrix,visited, fromRow - 1, fromColumn)) {
                left = routeExistsHelper(fromRow - 1, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix,visited);
            }
            if (validMove(mapMatrix,visited, fromRow, fromColumn + 1)) {
                up = routeExistsHelper(fromRow, fromColumn + 1, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix,visited);
            }
            if (validMove(mapMatrix,visited, fromRow, fromColumn - 1)) {
                down = routeExistsHelper(fromRow, fromColumn - 1, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix,visited);
            }
            return left || right || up || down;
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[][] mapMatrix = {
                {true, false, false},
                {true, true, false},
                {false, true, true}
        };
        System.out.println(routeExists(0, 0, 2, 2, mapMatrix));
        System.out.println(routeExists(2, 2, 0, 0, mapMatrix));
        System.out.println(routeExists(1, 1, 0, 0, mapMatrix));
        System.out.println(routeExists(1, 1, 0, 1, mapMatrix));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`routeExists()` needs to be a recursive method, i.e. a method that calls itself. When you write a recursive method you first need to write the terminating condition, i.e. if the condition is true then the method does not call itself. If the condition is false then the method should call itself but with different values for the method parameters.

In any method in java, even regular, non-recursive methods, you should always make sure that the method parameters are valid. Hence you need to first check that `toRow` and `toColumn` are valid.

You should think of the method parameters `fromRow` and `fromColumn` as the indexes of the cell in `mapMatrix` that you are currently in, and not where you started the matrix traversal from. Of-course, in the first call to method `routeExists()`, the values of parameters `fromRow` and `fromColumn` are the indexes of the start of the route.

There are five terminating conditions for method `routeExists()`.

1. If `mapMatrix[toRow][toColumn]` is false then a route does not exist, so the method must return false.
2. If `fromRow` is not a valid index for `mapMatrix` then the method must return false. Using your example, if `fromRow` equals 3 then the method must return false.
3. If `fromRow` is valid, then if `fromColumn` is not valid then the method must return false.
4. If both `fromRow` and `fromColumn` are valid, then if `mapMatrix[fromRow][fromColumn]` is false, the method must return false.
5. If `mapMatrix[toRow][toColumn]` is true then if `fromRow` equals `toRow` and `fromColumn` equals `toColumn`, that means you have reached the destination. In this case the method must return true.

If none of the above terminating conditions are met, then you need to progress to the next cell in `mapMatrix` and continue checking whether a route exists. In the code below, I arbitrarily decided to progress to the next row. If progressing to the next row does not find a route, I check the next column. Note that the order is not important. You can first move to the next column and after that move to the next row.

Here is the code.

```java
public class RoutePlanner {
    public static boolean routeExists(int fromRow,
                                      int fromColumn,
                                      int toRow,
                                      int toColumn,
                                      boolean[][] mapMatrix) {
        if (mapMatrix == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check method parameters for destination.
        if (toRow >= mapMatrix.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (toColumn >= mapMatrix[toRow].length) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check that destination is reachable.
        if (!mapMatrix[toRow][toColumn]) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check remaining method parameters.
        if (fromRow >= mapMatrix.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (fromColumn >= mapMatrix[fromRow].length) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!mapMatrix[fromRow][fromColumn]) {
            return false;
        }
        if (fromRow == toRow  &&  fromColumn == toColumn) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean exists = routeExists(fromRow + 1, fromColumn, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix);
        if (!exists) {
            exists = routeExists(fromRow, fromColumn + 1, toRow, toColumn, mapMatrix);
        }
        return exists;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[][] mapMatrix = {{true, false, false},
                                 {true, true, false},
                                 {false, true, true}};

        System.out.println(routeExists(0, 0, 2, 2, mapMatrix));
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not cover all cases, because it is not guaranteed that it will start at index 0,0, i.e. it is not guaranteed that initially fromRow == 0 and fromColumn == 0. And since you only check the path to the right and down, it might not check all possible paths.